# How do you use a command batch variable for itemspec parameter in tf.exe?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, tfs

I'm writing a batch file to do several different operations using the command line `tf.exe`. I want to set a local variable `_branchTopFolder` for the `itemspec` parameter without having to repeat the path multiple times. Here are my batch commands.

The first tf command is failing to understand I'm passing in a valid path. The command is using literally _branchTopFolder instead of the value of the variable. If I replace _branchTopFolder with the actual path, then the script runs fine.

It looks like the tf executable itself is parsing the argument and not not letting the command line console parse and pass on the value. Could there be an escape character to use that would be recognized by `tf.exe` to pass in a variable for parsing?

```
@Echo off 
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"

:: Clean up Branches
SET _branchTopFolder=C:\Projects\Company\Site\20130722

:: Report checked out files
tf status _branchTopFolder /user:* /recursive
PAUSE

:: GET top folder
tf get _branchTopFolder
PAUSE 

:: DELETE folder path 
tf delete _branchTopFolder
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the command line prompt return the VALUE of the variable, the variable is supposed to be wrapped in %%.

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"

:: Clean up Branches
SET _branchTopFolder=C:\Projects\Company\Site\20130722

:: Report checked out files
tf status %_branchTopFolder% /user:* /recursive
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

**Never** use the PATH variable for a single folder.  You can add a folder to the path but if you remove all the system paths from the PATH variable then it will break things.

Having said that, you have used `path = text` and in batch syntax it includes the spaces so you created a variable called `%path %` which doesn't behave like the system variable `%path%`

Use this syntax to add a folder to the path, with the leading semi-colon:

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

Comment: Setting PATH is for the specific instance of the command window. It does not impact the system level PATH. This is a good concern, but after researching it, it is not true. I am marking this a negative to make sure others following this question & answer are not mislead.
http://ss64.com/nt/path.html

Comment: @MADCookie No, it doesn't affect the greater system (outside of your batch file) but it's still bad practice.

Comment: @MADcookie Where did I say it will affect the global PATH? What it will do is stop your batch file from accessing all the external commands, and batch files rely on external commands for most batch file functions.